# Enabling HTTP_CONNECT for port 9418

Tags: proxy, git

I wish to configure the proxy to allow HTTP_CONNECT over port 9418 for git downloads . How should I go about doing it ?

Thanks .

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide a little more information to get an answer. Which proxy are you using and on which os?

Comment: Its a Cisco Content Engine proxy on Linux .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using squid. Adding

> acl Safe_ports port 9418         # git

with all the other "Safe_ports" lines in your squid.conf file should do it.